# Silverlight - tabs

Tags: silverlight

Using Silverlight5.

```
    <sdk:TabControl >
        <sdk:TabItem Header="Num1" IsSelected="True">
            <UserControls:Tab1Data />
        </sdk:TabItem>

        <sdk:TabItem Header="Num2" >
            <UserControls:Tab2Data />
        </sdk:TabItem>

    </sdk:TabControl>
```

Why is the constructor on the non selected tab called at runtime?

```
public partial class Tab2Data : UserControl
{
    public Tab2Data()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var x = 1; //set a breakpoint here and it hits when debugging the app
    }
}
```

I had read that by design tabs are only 'run' when pressed.

If this is by design, the I need to figure out in each constructor how to tell if it has been 'selected' so I can call the expensive db operations.  I don't want the whole app to load its db related data on startup (mostly drop down menus)

EDIT2:
I've wired up a selected check which gives the desired functionality..

```
private void TabOverallMain_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (TabItem)e.AddedItems[0];

    if (selectedItem.Header.ToString() == "Num2") {
        tab2Data.PopulateDropDowns();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not recommended to do heavy staff (loading from db etc) in controls constructors. Use 'loaded' event or 'NavigatedTo' for navigation pages. And don't forget about DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool property.